# What is the passive voice of "The noise attracted us."

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, passive-voice

Voice change of the sentence

> The noise attracted us.

Should it be

> We were attracted **by** the noise

or

> We were attracted **to** the noise.

Comment: Because this is basic grammar, can you go into more detail what you find difficult or confusing?  The passive of **attracted** is **were attracted** and, as with any passive construction, you swap the subject and the object.  Without more detail this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: This question gets asked from time to time, and I invariably want to know: Why is the OP asking about how to make this into the passive voice? I mean, is it an exercise from a book or something? Knowing why a question is being asked can help attract better answers.

Answer (score 2):

The two prepositions you ask about form prepositional verbs with "attracted" that mean different things.

> We were attracted **by** the noise.

This sentence is likely what you are looking for. It tells you the noise is the agent and emphasizes the action and its agent.

> We were attracted **to** the noise.

This sentence, on the other hand, stresses the directionality of the action. *We* were drawn **to** the noise. It tells you that *we* made a movement towards the noise.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation together with having much delighted with the utterance of JR 'knowing why a question is being asked can help attract better answers'.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, both "to" and "by" are grammatical, and both would be the passive of "the noise attracted us".  However they mean slightly different things, so it depends what you want to say:

"To" implies *direction*, and implies movement (or at least attention) *toward* the attraction.

> The children were quickly attracted **to** the clown handing out balloons.

"By" identifies the *agent* that is the *object* of attraction.

> The children were quickly attracted **by** the lights and colors of the game.

Comment: by implies an agent. But I agree with you.